# A simple question about permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

So I could not find an answer anywhere, so here it is:

If a string could be consisted of

x y x y x y x y

and x could only be used once, while y could be repeated, would it be correct to say that there are 
5*4*4*4*3*4*2*4*1 = 30720 possible combinations?

EDIT: There are five possible options for x, and four possible options for y. And as stated above,  each individual options for x can only be used once, while each individual option for y can be repeated.

EDIT2:Another way of saying the question:
 A string is written as xyxyxyxyx, where x represents one of five letters and y represents one of four letters (i.e. x is a, b, c, d or e and y is f, g, h or j). If the letters for x cannot repeat in the string, but the letters for y can repeat, how many possible strings can we make?

Comment: From your description, this seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my answer is the answer to your question but I'm going to rephrase the question to make it more clear. If it's right, please edit your post too so future searchers can more easily find it. If not, I may leave the answer up as it's an interesting variation.

The question is:

A string is written as $xyxyxyxyx$, where $x$ represents one of five letters and $y$ represents one of four letters (i.e. $x$ is a, b, c, d or e and $y$ is f, g, h or j). If the letters for $x$ cannot repeat in the string, but the letters for $y$ can repeat, how many possible strings can we make?

If this is your question then yes the answer is $5*4*4*4*3*4*2*4*1 = 30720$. Note that this is the same as if you asked how many possible strings $xxxxxyyyy$ are there? You can calculate the $x$-strings first, then the $y$-strings and multiply the numbers together.

Comment: This is what I mean